# trouble display MongoDB aggregates on Bottle Framework page

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, bottle

I am trying to display my MongoDB aggregate on a web page, but I am having an error hard to figure out. Relatively new on Bottle. Any help would be appreciated.

**My schema**

```
db.complaints.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e5990d991312e2c9b266e3"),
    "complaintID" : 1388734,
    "product" : "mortgage",
    "subProduct" : "conventional adjustable mortgage (arm)",
    "issue" : "loan servicing, payments, escrow account",
    "subIssue" : "",
    "state" : "va",
    "ZIP" : 22204,
    "submitted" : "web",
    "received" : "2015-05-22",
    "sent" : "2015-05-22",
    "company" : "green tree servicing, llc",
    "response" : "closed with explanation",
    "timely" : "yes",
    "disputed" : ""
}
```

**The python code**

```
import bottle
import pymongo
import sys
@bottle.route('/')
def home_page():
# connect to mongoDB
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)

# attach to test database

db = connection.customers
# get handle for names collection
complaints = db.complaints

# find a single document
aggr = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$product",  "Total_Product":{"$sum:1"}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Product":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0, "product":"$_id", "Total_Product":1}}])


return bottle.template('cfpb', {'username':"Browse Aggregate Analytics", 'things':aggr})



bottle.debug(True)
bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

**HTML Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
<head>
<title>Analytics </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
 {{username}}
<p>
<ul>
%for thing in things:
<li>{{thing[aggr]}}</li>
%end
</ul><p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am having an error

```
> Error: 500 Internal Server Error
>     InvalidDocument("cannot convert value of type <type 'set'> to bson",)
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
>     return route.call(**args)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
>     rv = callback(*a, **ka)
>     File "msc.py", line 16, in home_page
>     aggr = db.complaints.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$product", "Total_Product":{"$sum:1"}}},{"$sort":{"Total_Product":-1}},{"$project":{"_id":0,
> "product":"$_id", "Total_Product":1}}])
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1421, in aggregate
>     result = self._command(sock_info, cmd, slave_ok)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 191, in _command
>     allowable_errors)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 189, in command
>     self._raise_connection_failure(error)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 316, in _raise_connection_failure
>     raise error
>     InvalidDocument: cannot convert value of type <type 'set'> to bson
```

Comment: You asked it to return a cursor when you just want an array. Remove the cursor option from the aggregate command.

Comment: I am still getting an error @ Blakes Seven.

Comment: Please edit your question to show any changes applied. Why are you setting any options like cursor or allowDiskUse anyway? They are only needed for large result sets that would exceed what you would display in a template.

Comment: The cursor was how MongoDB recommends it start from 2.6 for a large doc. I am still getting the server error @ Blakes Seven

Comment: You have a typo around `$sum` with the quoting. The other point is an "cursor" and an "array" have different purposes. You just want an array here.

Comment: @Blakes Seven Thanks it was the typo by the $sum. Thank you so much. I highly appreciate.